# Redux funcion throws "callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to get a redux function to work, however, it throws me this error:

```
[TypeError: callback is not a function. (In 'callback(true, result)', 'callback' is undefined)]
```

The function is like this:

```
export function searchEvent(categories, privateEvent, eventName,
  eventCity, eventHourStart, eventHourFinish, eventDayStart, eventDayFinish, callback) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const ref = firestore().collection('events');

      if (categories.length > 0) {
        const promises = [];
        const allData = [];

        categories.forEach(e => {
          let query = ref.where(e.field, '==', e.value);

          if (privateEvent) {
            query = ref
              .where(e.field, '==', e.value)
              .where('isPrivateEvent', '==', true);
          }

          const promise = query.get().then(response => {
            const data = response.docs.map(d => d.data());
            let result = data;

            ...

            allData.push(...result);
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
          promises.push(promise);
        });

        console.log(allData);
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
          callback(true, allData);
        });
      } else {
        let query = ref;

        if (privateEvent) {
          query = ref.where('isPrivateEvent', '==', true);
        }

        query.get().then(response => {
          const data = response.docs.map(d => d.data());
          let result = data;

          ...

          console.log(result);
          callback(true, result);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure that I'm passing a callback to said function, as I'm doing it like so:

```
dispatchSearchEvent(categories, privateEvent, name, city,
  hourstart, hourfinish, daystart, dayfinish, (s, r) => {
   ...
});
```

So, why it tells me that 'callback' is not a function when I'm clearly passing a callback to it in order to make it work?
I'm still a newbie when it comes to react-redux stuff, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log` the parameters at the start of `searchEvent`? You may not be calling that method in the way you are expecting, it depends how you are wiring up your redux

Comment: @LukeStorry You're right, after a little bit of an analysis, I was able to tell that on the definition of the Redux funcion on the file where I call ```searchEvent```, I forgot to put some parameters, so the function was going crazy because of it. Thanks for your help.